# editing the initialize.php file so on my define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); what do i put in place of localhost. Using webuzo not Cpanel

Tags: database, server

if(!defined('DB_SERVER')) define('DB_SERVER',"localhost");

NB: I am using Webuzo not Cpanel

I did not try anything yet, I don't know if i should replace the localhost with webuzo or MySql. I am stuck i don't know what to think of